# Android RecyclerView Cards From AWS ScanRequest Data

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, android-recyclerview

I am creating cards with the information received from an AWS ScanRequest.
My current method works but is horribly slow and inefficient. Please let me know if you have any recommendations!

```
    ScanRequest scanRequest = new ScanRequest().withTableName(tableName);
    ScanResult result = dynamoDB.scan(scanRequest);
    for (Map<String, AttributeValue> item : result.getItems()) {
        name1 = item.get("name").toString().substring(4, item.get("name").toString().length() - 2);
        start1 = item.get("start").toString().substring(4, item.get("start").toString().length() - 2);
        end1 = (item.get("end")).toString().substring(4, item.get("end").toString().length() - 2);

        dataArray.add(name1);
        dataArray.add(start1);
        dataArray.add(end1);

        parts = chop(dataArray, 3);
    }

    adapter = new ActivityAdapter(getContext(), parts, getFragmentManager());
    rec = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.activityList);
    rec.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rec.setAdapter(adapter);
    llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    rec.setLayoutManager(llm);

static <T> List<List<T>> chop(List<T> list, final int L) {
    List<List<T>> parts = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    final int N = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i += L) {
        parts.add(new ArrayList<T>(
                        list.subList(i, Math.min(N, i + L)))
        );
    }
    return parts;
}
```

Comment: How slow and inefficient?

Comment: There are 10 attributes (not 3)  that I am collecting. My current method is returning the 1st item as a set of objects, then cycling back through the table and adding the second item to the tail of the first rather than returning it by its self. This happens till all of the items are a string of objects (1, 2, 3, 4...) I then am trimming the objects to get the desired data and "chop()" the string into (1), (2), (3), (4)... then to the adapter. There must be a way to return (1), (2), (3), (4)... without having to go through all that. I am very new to programming and would appreciate any advice!